# Expand environment variables in path

Tags: r

I want to expand environment variables in R like I can do this in Python:

```py
os.path.expandvars('$WHATEVER/hello/world')
```

However, the same does not work with `path.expand()`

```
path.expand('$WHATEVER/hello/world')
```

How can I do it anyway?

Comment: You may have to split the string and substitute occurrences of `$VAR` with the return value of `Sys.getenv("VAR")`. I'm not aware of a built in function that does this like `os.path.expandvars`.

Comment: @nrussell It's astonishing what you can do with R but even more what you *can't*. :D

Comment: It's certainly not a drop in replacement for Python, but then again it was never intended to be a general purpose scripting language like Python. Similarly, I would not recommend trying to develop a web browser in VBA.

Comment: @displayname I’m not sure I would underwrite this statement: R’s behaviour in this case seems entirely reasonable to me. Python’s `os.path.expandvars` does more out of the box but *it’s a different function* with a different purpose, and there are, after all, several ways of achieving the same result in R (e.g. `system("echo $WHATEVER/hello/world", intern = TRUE)`.

Comment: @nrussell Well it does have `path.expand('~')`. So why not finish the mile? ^^

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, not what I expected but this is actually something I was looking for. You could provide this as an answer I guess :D

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace_all` in the `stringi` package allows you to provide a function to do the calculation of replacement text, so this gets us very close.  Add in a custom regex for how you want to extract a valid variable reference add some `substr` and `getenv`, and you're home.

```
library(stringr)
expand <- function(params) {
    str_replace_all(
        params, 
        '\\$[A-Za-z_0-9]+', 
        function(s) Sys.getenv(substr(s, 2, str_length(s))))
}
```

Or, for `${...}` style variables:

```
library(stringr)
expand <- function(params) {
    str_replace_all(
        params, 
        '\\$\\{[^{}]+\\}', 
        function(s) Sys.getenv(substr(s, 3, str_length(s)-1)))
}
```

Finally, a version that checks `R` variables first, and falls-back to environment variables if not found:

```
.osEnv <- Sys.getenv()
# Coalesce
`%?%` <- function(a, b) {
    n <- is.null(a);
    if (any(n)) a[n] <- b[n];
    a;
}
expand <- function(params)
    str_replace_all(params, '\\$\\{([^{}]+)\\}',
                    function(s) {
                        name <- substr(s, 3, str_length(s) - 1);
                        val <- get0(name) %?% .osEnv[[name]];
                    })
```